# How to create role based routing in react-router-dom v5

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am working on one application. in the application there are various types of users like Admin, User, and Super Admin. I have to implement Route based authentication so that user cannot access Super Admin or Admin routes, And Admin cannot access Super Admin Routes. I have implemented that, but how can make it better and more clear?

```
import React from "react"
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom"

const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, AccessTo, ...rest }) => (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props => {
        if (!localStorage.getItem("user")) {
          return (
            <Redirect
              to={{ pathname: "/", state: { from: props.location } }}
            />
          )
        }
        else if (localStorage.getItem("user") && AccessTo === "admin") {
            return <Component {...props} />
        }
        else if (localStorage.getItem("user") && AccessTo !== "admin") {
            return <h2> You are not authorized to view this page </h2>
        } 
      }}
    />
)

export default ProtectedRoute
```